# Loop to cumpute sum of numbers 1 through n in python.for example if i say n=3 , it should show (6)=(1+2+3)

Tags: python-3.x

i cant write this program.i think it is need to a function.

```
number1=int(input("Enter your number : ")
number2=number1-1
number3=1+(number2-1)
```

Comment: What is your question? I suggest revising your question entirely: title + body.

Answer (score -1):

you can write the code like :

```
number1=int(input("Enter your number : ")
def show(n):
    s=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        s=s+i
    print(s)
show(number1)
```

Answer (score -1):

num = input("Enter a number to calculate sum")

num = int(num)

sum = num * (num + 1) / 2

print("Sum of the first ", num , "natural numbers using formula is: ", sum )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).